# Can't get DGV item by indexing Item(3,0)

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm using this Visual Basic 2008 code to display the dgv values from the database:

```
Public Sub getAppt()
    Try
        sqlusers = "SELECT bcId, barCode, bcPlate, custFname + ' ' + custLname AS Expr1 FROM dbo.tblBC"
        dgvBC.DataSource = con.ReturnQuery(sqlusers)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Cannot find database!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
```

The table would be like this:

```
bcID       barCode       bcPlate       Expr1
 1       1234567890      ABC111      John Smith
 2       1230987645      ABC112      Mary Jhonson
 3       1230923455      ABC113      Taylor Swift
```

I'm trying to get the name for the `barcode = 1234567890`
I want this to happen automatically so when I scan the code, the name appears on a message box. I tried putting the code on a textbox and put this code in TextChanged:

```
MsgBox(dgvBC.Item(3, 0).Value)
```

but it gives me this error:

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index
```

Comment: I would start here... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158656%28v=vs.110%29.aspx . Also telling us you want it to automatically do this when you scan the code doesnt give us anything... I would suggest changing your post on exactly where your stuck... Also that error is self explanitory and if you visit the link you will know why... One more thing dont post a "can you show me how" if you cant bother putting in what you have done; refering to the automatically part you posted... Turn Option Strict on to, its your friend.